# Get object array promise, then iterate over objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I am trying to create an array called pw_array, assign the contents of pw_subscribers to that array, then append each object in the pw_array with new key value pairs from the second promise. I am new to promises and having a lot of trouble making this work. Right now when I console.log(pw_customer) inside the second promise, inside the getCustomers function, it is returning what I want. But when I console.log(pw_array) later it is the original array.

```
var pw_array = [];
//first promise is working correctly
var getPaywhirlSubscribers = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

paywhirl.Subscriptions.getsubscribers({limit:100}, function(error, pw_subscribers) {
        Promise.all(JSON.parse(pw_subscribers).forEach(function(pw_subscriber) {
             pw_array.push(pw_subscriber);
        }))
        // console.log(pw_array);
        return resolve(pw_array);
    });
});

var getGatewayReferences = function(pw_array) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Promise.all(pw_array.forEach(function(pw_customer) {
            paywhirl.Customers.getCustomer(pw_customer.customer_id, function(error, customer) {
                pw_customer.phone = customer.phone;
                pw_customer.address = customer.address;
                pw_customer.gateway_reference = customer.gateway_reference;
                // this console.log is returning what I want
                // console.log(pw_customer);
            }); 
        }));
        resolve(pw_array);
        // console.log(pw_array);
    });
};
```

and the promise chain...

```
getPaywhirlSubscribers.then(getGatewayReferences).then(function(pw_array) {
  // this console.log is returning the original pw_array with pw_subscribers but not with the appended pw_customer keys
  console.log(pw_array);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `pw_array.map` instead of `pw_array.forEach`, and for the map return the `paywhirl.Customers.getCustomer(...` (which I assume makes a promise).
This way the next `.then` will have all the customers.

Comment: @asosnovsky is correct you are only mutating each item in the `pw_array` given to you by the `forEach`. Those items are not "connected live" to the original `pw_array` at that time. You should use `.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your code can be reduced to

```
var getPaywhirlSubscribers = function() {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    paywhirl.Subscriptions.getSubscribers({limit:100}, function(err, subs) {
      if (err) {
        rej(err);
      } else {
        res(JSON.parse(subs));
      }
    });
  });
};

var gatewayRefs = function(promiseOfArray) {
  return promiseOfArray.then(function(subs) {
    return Promise.all(subs.map(function(sub) {
      return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        paywhirl.Customers.getCustomer(sub.customer_id, function(err, customer) {
          if (err) {
            rej(err);
          } else {
            res(Object.assign({}, sub, customer);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
};

gatewayRefs(getPaywhirlSubscribers()).then(function(arrayOfCustomers) {
  // do something with the customer array
});
```

Note that you can make this even shorter/simpler if you use one of the many utilities available to automatically convert node.js-style error -first callback APIs into Promise-based ones. Search for 'promise denodeify'.

You could also conceivably pull some of the steps out into a `.then` chain to reduce nesting, but that's as much aesthetic as practical IMHO.

Comment: @David no problem. Just remember that you can't 'unbox' a Promise (like putting the values in an external array). You have to deal with the data *only* in a `.then` handler. Just keep chaining.